# Kubernetes - writing data to volume of StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to create a StatefulSet. I want to create a file on the attached volume so i am using this command **touch /data/test.txt** but it seems like the container crashes because of that. Why would it do that? If i don't use the command everything works fine. What are the properties of the /data directory mounted to volume? Like read/write permissions.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 3 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /data
        args:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - touch /data/test.txt
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: What state do you expect the pod to be in?  (`touch` won't stay running and doesn't listen on port 80, so when the main container process exits, Kubernetes will restart it, and when it needs to restart it multiple times, the pod will ultimately end up in `CrashLoopBackOff` state.)

Comment: It's not crashing because of the command per se. It's crashing because you overwrite the default command `nginx -g daemon off;` by touch, and while the other command is there to have nginx up and running, your command just created that file and stops. You can append nginx command after your touch. Should work.

Comment: You can use the approach mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928828/1753098

Answer (score 1):

Because the default [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of **k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8** would be `nginx start` or something likely.

So, if you want to inject the image, you need to set **command**

```
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args:
          - |
            touch /data/test.txt
```

And you can `kubectl describe` or `kubectl logs` to see what's wrong with your pod/deployment.